# como puedo resolver el error "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute()"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, crud

estoy trabajando el crud que ya tenia hecho y funcionaba en postgre , pero cambie la base de datos a mysql y no me funcionan las funciones , siguen funcionando normal e postgre pero con mysql me sale ese error , y aunque use el query() las funciones setFetchMode() y fetchAll() me sale el mismo error " on null "

mis datos de la bd son estos

```
    define('SERVIDOR',  'mysql');
    define('HOST',      'localhost');
    define('BD',        'HOD');
    define('PORT',      '5432');
    define('CHARSET',   'utf8');   

    // MYSQL
    
    define('USER1',         'root');
    define('PASSWORD1',     '');
```

mi clase conexion esta

```
    ini_set("max_execution_time", "0");
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    
    use PDO as pdo;
    
    class BASE_DATOS extends PDO
    {

    private $servidor = SERVIDOR;

    private $host     = HOST;
    private $port     = PORT;
    private $bd       = BD;
    private $charset  = CHARSET;

    private $user_mysql     = USER1;
    private $password_mysql = PASSWORD1;

    private $user_pgsql     = USER2;
    private $password_pgsql = PASSWORD2;

    private $repetir_conexion;
    private $error_conexion;
  

    public function __construct()
    {
        // $conexion = NULL;

    switch ($this->servidor) 
    {

    case 'mysql':

        $opciones = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,            
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT       => true,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES  \'UTF8\''
        );
            try 
        {
            $conexion = parent::__construct(
                "$this->servidor:
                    host       =   $this->host     ;
                    port       =   $this->port     ;
                    dbname     =   $this->bd       ;
                    user       =   $this->user_mysql     ;
                    password   =   $this->password_mysql ;
                "
            );
            parent::setAttribute($opciones);

            $this->repetir_conexion = true;
            $this->error_conexion   = "";
            $this->comprobar = "Conexion Exitosa";

            return $conexion;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error_conexion = 'Ha surgido un error y no se puede conectar a la base de datos. Detalle: ' . $e->getMessage();
            $this->comprobar = "Conexion Fallida !";  
            return $conexion;    
        }
            break;

        case 'pgsql':

        $opciones = [
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT       => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
           try 
        {
            $conexion = parent::__construct(
                "$this->servidor:
                    host       =   $this->host     ;
                    port       =   $this->port     ;
                    dbname     =   $this->bd       ;  
                    user       =   $this->user_pgsql     ;
                    password   =   $this->password_pgsql ;
                "
            );
            parent::setAttribute($opciones);
            $this->repetir_conexion = true;
            $this->error_conexion   = "";
            $this->comprobar = "Conexion Exitosa";

            return $conexion; 

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error_conexion = 'Ha surgido un error y no se puede conectar a la base de datos. Detalle: ' . $e->getMessage();
            $this->comprobar = "Conexion Fallida !";  
            return $conexion;    
        }
            break;
        
        default:
            echo "ERROR! El Gestor De Base De Datos No Es Reconocido";
            break;
    }

    }

    public function Probar_Conexion()
    {return $this->comprobar;}

    public function getRepetir_Conexion()
    {return $this->repetir_conexion;}

    public function getError_Conexion()
    {return $this->error_conexion;}


    }
```

y mi codigo de consulta es este , aun no he intentado el insert o el update por que no he avanzado con el la consulta , y la mayor parte de las tablas son relacionadas por eso de tener la consulta lista

```
    <?php

    class Modelo
    {
        
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->conexion = new BASE_DATOS();
     
        }

        public function Cerrar_BD()
        {
            return $this->conexion->close();
        }
    }
```

y esta es la clase donde esta la funcio consulta

```
      class Secciones_Class extends Modelo {  

    private $trayecto;
    private $nombre;
    private $anio; 

    public function setSeccion($trayecto, $nombre, $anio)
    {
        $this->trayecto = $trayecto;
        $this->nombre   = $nombre;
        $this->anio     = $anio;
    }
    public function getTracyecto()
    {
        return $this->trayecto;
    }

    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function getAnio()
    {
        return $this->anio;
    }
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); 
    }


    function Trayecto () {
    
        $tabla            = "SELECT * FROM trayecto ORDER BY idtrayecto ASC";
        $respuestaArreglo = '';
        try { 
            $datos = $this->conexion->prepare($tabla);
             $datos->execute();
             $datos->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $respuestaArreglo = $datos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $respuestaArreglo;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            $errorReturn = ['estatus' => false];
            $errorReturn += ['info' => "error sql:{$e}"];
            return $errorReturn;
        }
    }  

  }
```

Comment: as intentando un `try{ //codigo }catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}` para ver que mensaje sale o si hay un error en la conexion??? porque ese no es el puerto default de mysql

Comment: Parece que no está conectando, puedes probarlo poniendo un `if ($this->conexión) { // lanzar consulta } else {  // no hay conexión... Supongo que tienes un manejador de errores... Es hora de usarlo }` Debes tener en cuenta que el DSN no se construye igual para todas las BD, que el puerto podría no ser el mismo, etc. En el `case` para `mysql` no veo que estés tomando eso en cuenta. Revisa la documentación para el caso específico de MySQL y crea el DSN del modo indiciado allí.

Comment: y como puede saber cual es el puerto default de mysql?,  la verdad esta conexion no se si funciona  o no , no me lanza error pero tampoco conecta al mysql , intente con en el insert pero tampoco guarda datos, y tiene que ser obligatoriamente heredando de de PDO no me permiten usar  $pdo = new PDO()

Comment: Sí te dejan, lo que pasa es que la clase hereda de PDO y en  vez de hacer el `new` directamente le pasas los parámetros al constructor de la clase padre (que es PDO): `$conexion = parent::__construct( "$this->servidor: host = $this->host ; port = $this->port ; dbname = $this->bd ; user = $this->user_mysql ; password = $this->password_mysql ; " );` Esos datos que pasas en el `case mysql` deben ser los correctos para MySQL. El puerto por defecto suele ser el `3306` o el `3307` y en muchos casos ni siquiera es necesario pasar el puerto. Revisa el Manual de PHP, está todo explicado ahí.

Comment: gracias ya resolvi el error